# Setting Labels to a GridPane in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

I have a GridPane called matrix in a FXML file, and in the controller I am adding a label to each cell of the GridPane, however I am not able to center that label in the GridPane. I have tried setting all kinds of alignments. 
Here is some of my code: This is all in a for loop by the way

```
for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < label[i].length; j++) {
               label[i][j] = new Label();
               label[i][j].setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
               label[i][j].setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
               label[i][j].setCenterShape(true);
               label[i][j].setText("" + randomNumber);
               matrix.add(label[i][j], j, i);
            }
}
```

How would I horizontally center the label in matrix cell. Please Help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
GridPane.setHalignment(label[i][j], HPos.CENTER);
```

([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHalignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.HPos-))